# Integrating Password Manager Into iPhone App

Tags: ios, passwords, react-native

I've noticed a few iPhone apps have started to allow you to use your password manager to sign in. Slack is an example of this:

[image: Slack login]

[image: Slack password manager]

It looks like there's a link that's triggering a partial version of the share toolbar in Safari which lets you access your favourite password manager's widget. That's all I've been able to figure out so far though.

My question is, how have they got this functionality into their app? I'm primarily developing things using React Native, but if it needs a custom component then that's not a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at [generic-password-app-extension](https://github.com/joelastpass/generic-password-app-extension) which gives you access to password managers. It's provided by the creators of Last Password and 1Password.

You'll obviously need to wrap it with a native component so you can trigger it from your JS code.

Comment: if only react-native had integrated this as a native component

Comment: For iOS 12+ and react-native 0.60+, this is now supported natively without the need for an extension or custom code. Added a solution with links to the appropriate documentation.

Answer (score 5):

This is now supported natively by iOS 12+ (and by react-native 0.60+) without the need for an extension.

- Documentation for enabling it on iOS is located [here on Apple's site](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/about_the_password_autofill_workflow).
  TLDR is to set the `UITextContentType` values of `.username` and `.password` for your inputs and, optionally, add an associated domain entitlement so your app can share passwords with your website.
- The prop for enabling it in React Native is [documented here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#autocompletetype). TLDR there is to provide an `autoCompleteType` on your `TextInput` component. The two OSes should handle that properly, though again you will have to add an associated domain if you want to share passwords between your website and app.

Comment: This is now `textContentType` for iOS (https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#textcontenttype-ios) and `autoComplete` for Android (https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#autocomplete-android).